# displaying sum or grand total using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code:

```
    // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
$('.Price').keyup(function () {

    // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
    var sum = 0;
    var tax = document.getElementById('Tax').value;

    // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
    // and compute the sum for each loop

    $('.SubTotal').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    // set the computed value to 'totalPrice' textbox
    $('#GrandTotal').val(+sum + tax);


});
```

If sum total is 1800 & tax is 350 then Grandtotal appears as: 1800350 & not 2150

What have i done wrong?

Comment: you never converted tax from a string to a number so javascript treated the whole thing as a string

Comment: how is it done? @Bindrid please help

Answer (score 0):

By default `tax` is read as String so when '350' is added to 1800 it becomes 1800350 . So first you have to convert tax into a Number Object then add it.

Like this

```
 // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
$('.Price').keyup(function () {

    // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
    var sum = 0;
    var tax = document.getElementById('Tax').value;

    // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
    // and compute the sum for each loop

    $('.SubTotal').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    // set the computed value to 'totalPrice' textbox
    $('#GrandTotal').val(+Number(sum) + Number(tax));


});
```